# How to run opencv4nodejs VideoCapture inside a raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, opencv, raspberry-pi

I've added the opencv4nodejs library to my raspberry pi package, I'm trying to access the picam 2 video camera, but I keep getting the error "Error: VideoCapture::New - failed to open capture". The script I'm running is as following:

```
import * as cv from 'opencv4nodejs'

async function main() {
  const wCap = new cv.VideoCapture(0);
  const intvl = setInterval(() => {
    let frame = wCap.read();
    // loop back to start on end of stream reached
    if (frame.empty) {
      wCap.reset();
      frame = wCap.read();
    }
    console.log(frame);
  }, 0);
}

main()
```

FWIW, I'm running this inside docker on a raspberry pi 3b+, using resin.io to deploy the images.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

on the pi before your script runs? Otherwise, opencv will not properly recognize your picam.

Answer (score 2):

Here the neat commands I run every-time I boot up the pi

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cd 
 cd /dev
 sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
 v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

Comment: Also, if you want the Pi to automatically run scripts every time it boots up, you can follow the instructions here: https://www.wikihow.com/Execute-a-Script-at-Startup-on-the-Raspberry-Pi

Answer (score 0):

I followed the approach of [@MForMarlon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223152/mformarlon) and [@z Eyeland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9636850/z-eyeland) and set this up automatically each time the pi boots.

However, the instructions for [running a script on boot](https://www.wikihow.com/Execute-a-Script-at-Startup-on-the-Raspberry-Pi) did not work for me, so here is my combined solution:

1) Create a script at root: `nano ~/setuppicamera.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

- Save the script by pressing `ctrl-x` and then `y` and then `enter`

2) Make the script executable: `chmod +x ~/setuppicamera.sh`

3) Add the script to the desktop autostart file:

- Open the autostart file: `sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`
- Create a new line above `@xscreensaver -no-splash` and add `@/home/pi/setuppicamera.sh`
- Save the file: `ctrl-x` then `y` then `enter`

Now every time you reboot you should be able to access the picamera at source 0.

To test that it worked, reboot your pi with `sudo reboot` and then run `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`. You should see output along the lines of:

```
mmal service 16.1 (platform:bcm2835-v4l2):
    /dev/video0
```

If you instead see `Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory` something went wrong. Double check the steps above and try again. Note that your picamera must be connected at the time of boot for this script to work properly.